# How to output mysqli_fetch_field_direct?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to convert this code from mysql to mysqli. But when I print it and open in excel file I got an error.

> **Catchable fatal error**:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in **C:\xampplite\htdocs\app\text2.php** on line **139**

Can someone Teach me how to convert this code in mysqli correctly?

```
<?PHP

//EDIT YOUR MySQL Connection Info:
$DB_Server = "localhost";        //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "root";                 //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "";                //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "app";                //your MySQL Database Name
$DB_TBLName = "purchase_order";                //your MySQL Table Name
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app"); 
//$DB_TBLName,  $DB_DBName, may also be commented out & passed to the browser
//as parameters in a query string, so that this code may be easily reused for
//any MySQL table or any MySQL database on your server
if (isset($_POST['supp'])) {
$var = $_POST['supp'];
//DEFINE SQL QUERY:
//edit this to suit your needs
$result = $mysqli->query("Select id, counter, supplier, quantity, unit_cost, SUM(quantity*unit_cost) total_amount from $DB_TBLName where supplier='$var' GROUP BY id");
}
//Optional: print out title to top of Excel or Word file with Timestamp
//for when file was generated:
//set $Use_Titel = 1 to generate title, 0 not to use title
$Use_Title = 1;
//define date for title: EDIT this to create the time-format you need
$now_date = DATE('m-d-Y H:i');
//define title for .doc or .xls file: EDIT this if you want
$title = "Dump For Table $DB_TBLName from Database $DB_DBName on $now_date";
/*

Leave the connection info below as it is:
just edit the above.

(Editing of code past this point recommended only for advanced users.)
*/
//create MySQL connection

//execute query



//if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
//if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1))
{
     $file_type = "msword";
     $file_ending = "doc";
}ELSE{
     $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
     $file_ending = "xls";
}
//header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
HEADER("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MDT_DB_$now_date.$file_ending");
HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
HEADER("Expires: 0");

/*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */

IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         //ECHO("$title\n\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\n"; //new line character
while($row = $result->mysqli_fetch_row())
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
         //define field names
         $field_name = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$j);
         //will show name of fields
         $schema_insert .= "$field_name:\t";
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j])) {
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                 }
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "") {
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                 }
             ELSE {
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                 }
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         //end of each mysql row
         //creates line to separate data from each MySQL table row
         PRINT "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
     }
}ELSE{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR EXCEL DOCUMENTS ('.xls')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         //ECHO("$title");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

     //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
     FOR ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields($result); $i++)
     {
         ECHO mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i) . "\t";
     }
     PRINT("\n");
     //end of printing column names

     //start while loop to get data
     while($row = $result->mysqli_fetch_row())
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j]))
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "")
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
             ELSE
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         //following fix suggested by Josue (thanks, Josue!)
         //this corrects output in excel when table fields contain \n or \r
         //these two characters are now replaced with a space
         $schema_insert = PREG_REPLACE("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         PRINT "\n";
     }
}
?>
```

And this the error line

```
 137    FOR ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields($result); $i++)
 138    {
 139        ECHO mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i) . "\t";
 140    }
```

Comment: please use lowercase for functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not echo out the output from [`mysqli_fetch_field_direct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php) because it:

> Returns an object which contains field definition information from the
> specified result set.

instead try something like this ([from PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php)) to get a sense of what the returned object contains:

```
$finfo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i);

printf("Name:     %s\n", $finfo->name);
printf("Table:    %s\n", $finfo->table);
printf("max. Len: %d\n", $finfo->max_length);
printf("Flags:    %d\n", $finfo->flags);
printf("Type:     %d\n", $finfo->type);
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with `fetch_field_direct` ... you could do that and then each result in the loop will ouput

Comment: It's not echo the records in table and I received this error <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysqli_fetch_row() in <b>C:\xampplite\htdocs\app\text2.php</b> on line <b>151</b><br />

Comment: line 151 is while($row = $result->mysqli_fetch_row())

Comment: are you checking to see if the query returns any rows? try this: `$result = $mysqli->query("Select id, counter, supplier, quantity, unit_cost, SUM(quantity*unit_cost) total_amount from $DB_TBLName where supplier='$var' GROUP BY id");
printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);`

Comment: You can also echo var_dump() the variable in question to figure out what's inside...

Answer (score 0):

Try This 
put this code before `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");` line

`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED );`

Answer (score 0):

You're not using mysqli_fetch_row() correctly.

If you are going to use the object oriented style you need to use

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row())
```

However, if you're going to use the procedural style

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
```

You just had things a little backward :)

[Smack me with some mysqli!!!!](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)